# Regarding Issue in retrieval data from mapping

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, contract-invocation, contract-debugging

Here's the smart contract.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.8;

contract RecordCreation {

uint public count;
mapping (address => string) public usertype;
struct Patientdetails{

}
Patientdetails[] public patientdetails;

mapping (address => uint[]) public PatientDocuments;
function RecordCreation(){

}
//Function user type definition
function userDefinition(string utype1) payable returns(bool result) {

}
 //Data Submission Function
 function patientDataSubmission() payable returns (bool result){

 }
 //Documents Count Retrieval Function for  a Patient
 function countOfDataSubmission(address patientaddress) payable returns (uint result){

 }
 function getPatientsCount(address patientaddress)
    constant returns (uint count) {

 }

}
```

How can I define the contract for usecase -Patient holds any number of documents?

Comment: I can sort it out but it calls for a data restructure and I need some clarity about what we're trying to achieve. Does each patient have a document with basic info, PLUS a series of related documents, or is it JUST a series of documents related to patient ID?

Comment: A series of documents related to patient Id @Rob Hitchens

Comment: @Rob Hitchens How can I restructure it??

Comment: It sounds like you're aiming for this: https://medium.com/@robhitchens/enforcing-referential-integrity-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-a9ab1427ff42.

Comment: @RobHitchens I have followed your writeup..It worked perfectly.....It's good article to follow...Thank you once again

Comment: Hey, Chris. That's great. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're aiming for this: https://medium.com/@robhitchens/enforcing-referential-integrity-in-ethereum-smart-contracts-a9ab1427ff42